# Angular ng-view slide animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am trying to implement slide animation of ng-view from [Animation ng view example](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1).

css:

```
.header{
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    height: 380px;
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
}
.left{
    flex:0 0 300px;
}
.right {
    flex: 1;
    border: solid;
}
.slide {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}

.slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}

.slide.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

what i get [my animation](http://codepen.io/a191919/pen/GqgjZG)

But instead of good animation i getted something strange. How to fix this? I want to get animation like on example. What i am making wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's your styling for the html containers

```
.left{
    flex:0 0 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    border: solid;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```